# Mount arduino metro mini

Tags: enclosure

I'm using an Arduino Metro Mini (for example https://www.adafruit.com/product/2590) in a project, and want to mount it so the micro USB socket is available through a hole in the case.

Is there an easy way to do this? The main difficulty is that the board has to be mounted end-on to the case, which means you need brackets, which also need standoffs since of course neither side of the board is entirely flat; and the screw holes are at the very end, so no space to spare between them and the case. Etc. If that's not clear, glance at the analogous HDMI mount linked below.

Adafruit sells a complete enclosure (https://www.adafruit.com/product/2709), and there's a similar printable one at https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:936519. I could glue that to the case and then put the mini in there. But that seems like overkill.

For some breakout boards Adafruit has a special panel mount (like the HDMI one at https://www.adafruit.com/product/3121) -- but nothing I see there or elsewhere for the metro mini.

Any better solutions out there? Closest i've seen here is [Mounting Arduino in an enclosure](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/21603/mounting-arduino-in-an-enclosure)

Comment: are you asking how to mount a device that has 4 holes for screws? ... your question is not really related to the arduino

Comment: The USB micro specification includes clearance for mounting through a case. You notice when you plug a cable in there is *always* a small gap between the socket and the moulded body of the plug. That gap is for the housing of your project. Get a box with a thin enough wall, Cut a hole in it the right shape. Stick / glue / tape / velcro / screw / whatever your board so the socket is behind (and maybe partially inside) the hole you cut. It's not rocket surgery.

Comment: What do you mean "neither side of the board is entirely flat"?  Looking at the linked picture of the Arduino Metro Mini it looks to be a perfectly flag rectangular piece of PC board with mounting holes in all 4 corners. Attach a stand-off to every one of those holes, and position the Arduino near the edge of the case so that it's USB connector is barely inside. Measure and cut a hole in the case large enough to insert a USB plug.

Comment: i would copy the thingiverse stl object into tinkercad, where i can make a case around it, cutting out parts as needed. you can mount it  "upside-down" on a corner of the case, which lets you press the button with a paper clip. i did just that for nodeMCUs, though eventually i gave up on the imported bracket and make my own with a few cylinders and holes...

Answer (score 1):

What I've done for my projects is to get PC board standoffs of the right height, and use those to mount the board to the bottom of the case.

I measured the height of the USB connector and it's distance from the mounting holes, and calculated where to cut a hole in the side of the case for the USB connector.

I did not look up the USB specification for the depth/clearance of the connector - I just "guesstimated" and it worked fine.